# node-mailer send emails with dynamic 'from' email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

hello is there any configurations to send emails using dynamic from emails. current code.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'test@test.com',
            pass: 'test' 
        }
});

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
     return  res.send(500);
    }
     return res.send('ok');
 });



mailOptions = {
   from: zuserEmail.replyToEmail,
   to: data.email, 
   subject: subject,
   html: mBody
};
```

here I need to set the from email dynamically, and its not working properly. email is received successfully and always receiving email from "test@test.com" auth user email. is there any way to do so.

Comment: this could be due to your using gmail smtp.. why dont you use sendgrid ?
https://sendgrid.com